# Optgroup + value multiple select with selected2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to concatenate optgroup but the value of the select.
In jsFiddle when the select is simple selection it works normal.
When selecting the `São Paulo` value the correct result: *Sudeste - São Paulo*
But when I change the select to multiple shuffles it around.

Look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb8b7f2b/1/).

Comment: Please explain better what is the problem? What is your expected result? Where this is failling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `format(item)` function isn't getting the selected item's parent `optgroup` is that, when the function runs, the `option` isn't actually selected yet. At this point, the select2 plugin has not marked the `option` as selected in the underlying `select` tag.

If you debug `format(item)`, you can see that `$('#estados').find(':selected')` is an empty array the first time the function runs.

Instead, what you need to do is get the `option` element out of the `item` parameter, then use it in a query to get the `optgroup`.

```
function format(item) {
  // opt = $('#estados').find(':selected');
  // sel = opt.text();
  // og = opt.closest('optgroup').attr('label');

  var og = $(item.element[0]).closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  return og+'-'+item.text;
}
```

Comment: Excuse my English, I was really what I wanted.